# To add attributes to a thing

Tags: word-request

I want to use a beautiful word in my story that will mean: "**to add attributes to a thing**".

What word could I use? So far I have found only "**imbue**". I like the way it sounds but am unsure whether it fits in.

> A blacksmith has made a titanium staff that he gives to a magician so that he adds magic attributes to it in order to make it a magic staff. So the magician reads a special spell and magical energy wraps the entire staff and then he reads a second spell *(which identifies the magic)* and the energy soaks into the staff. With that the staff becomes a magic one and inherits the power of the second spell *(fire, ice, wind, water, pulse, electricity, plasma, e.t.c)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you writing Game of Thrones fan fiction? :-)

Yes, ***imbue*** is actually a great word to use. ***Imbue*** connotes the absorbing of energy. It is usually used with a positive connotation. For example, one's life can be "imbued with light" or "imbued with love." It is occasionally used negatively. For example, a childhood can be imbued with sadness or hatred.

***Imbue*** is often used to describe physical things, such as a crystal imbued with magic properties, or a book imbued with wisdom.

But perhaps the best word to use is ***enchant***. In World of Warcraft, Dungeons & Dragons and countless other role playing games, enchanters are magicians who add magical powers to ordinary weapons or armor or talismans.

So I would say, enchanting an item is the act of adding magic to it. During the process of adding magic to it, the magician is likely to imbue the item with energies or powers.

Comment: So either word will do, but **enchant** definitely implies "*magic*" right? The word **imbue** however, as you say, should follow "*with what*"?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to write a kind of Diablo-like & Hellgate:London+Star Wars+Skyrim sort of thing with a bit of Mass Effect and Supernatural.

Comment: Well, "enchant" doesn't always mean magical. A woman can be enchanting. (A man, too, but that is less common, I think.) I would use both words, as I describe at the end of my answer. Yes, "imbue" is really only used with "with": You imbue a glaive with +3 Save Vs. Petrify.

Comment: I loved diablo and diablo 2! right up there with everquest 2, haha. you must know all about enchanting items, right??

Comment: I really forgot the word "**enchant**". And I remember meeting "**imbue**" somewhere in the Diablo universe. Guess it's sunken deep in my mind.

Comment: I guess enchating isn't a part of diablo. in world of warcraft, becoming an enchanter is the best way to become rich, because the high-level magic items are a big part of the economy. But you end up spending many hours trying to gather together components for your spells.

Comment: What about making up a word like "**magicificate**" or "**magicize**", or even "**magicate**"?

Comment: I don't like any of those, to be honest. That's not to say you shouldn't make up a word, but it would have to be better than those, I think. ***Magicize*** sounds the least awkward, but they all sound awkward to me.

Comment: This page seems to have a few options: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/enchant  ***Ensorcell*** which I've never heard before. ***Augment***, also an old D&D term. Also, you can ***charm*** an item, that's a legit synonym. It implies less magic than ***enchant***, perhaps a temporary spell like an illusion.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll end up using **enchant** and **imbue**.

Comment: Augment can be used to mean a +2 sword is now a +4 sword. But yeah, can't go wrong with enchant and imbue

Comment: You should ask the RPG stack!

Comment: I'll give it a try later